# My website root is subfolder, how to fix it?

Tags: php

I have problem, `dirname(__FILE__)` still return **/home/vandy/www/wp-content/themes/theme** but I need the shape **http://mywebsiteurl.com/wp-content/themes/theme**

How delete the /home/vandy/www/ ?

How can I do that please?

Thanks for answer

Comment: did you try document root instead?

Comment: yes but with negative result

Answer (score 0):

Actual path of php file:

```
echo dirname(__FILE__);
```

Actual link of php file:

```
echo "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: But I need relativepath, no abspath

Comment: @FriedePetr  Play around with `$_SERVER` until you figure it out.

Comment: This is what i need return dirname($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]) . $File ;

Answer (score 0):

You are usually better off using `__FILE__` and using it to build your URI.  Look into the global `$_SERVER` array for some of the additional information you will need.